# How to write !isNew() in apex if condition

Tags: apex

I wrote like below. if condition is for checking if the record is existed not new record.

```
if(acc.Id !=null){
//logic
}
```

Comment: What's the context you're working with? A trigger? Flow? VIsualforce? Lightning?

Comment: if condition in trigger

Comment: Is this a before trigger by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Trigger.isInsert()` to determine if you're creating a new record or not, or you can use `Trigger.isUpdate()` to see if it is an update or not. In "before insert" triggers, Id is null, but in "after insert" triggers, the Id values are already assigned.

```
if(Trigger.isUpdate()) {
```

... or ...

```
if(!Trigger.isInsert()) {
```